# linearly dependent family of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Can someone help me to solve this question please :

Establish, by induction, that : $ \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0,1 \} \ \forall v_1 , \dots , v_n \in \mathbb{R}^n $ linearly independants :

$ \mathcal{B}_{C_n^2} = \{ (v_1 - v_2) , (v_1 - v_3) , \ \dots \ , (v_1 - v_n) , ( v_2 - v_3 ) , ( v_2 - v_4 ) , \ \dots \ , (v_2 - v_n) , \ \dots \ , ( v_{n-1} - v_n ) \} $

is a family of linearly dependent vectors of $ \mathbb{R}^n $.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Well, actually in $\Bbb R^n$ any more than $n$ vectors are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you. It's easy as a question. :)

Comment: The statement is wrong for $n = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick a telescoping sum, then add in the correction term:
$(v_1-v_2)+(v_2-v_3)+\cdots+(v_{n-1}-v_n)-(v_1-v_n)=0$

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much.  :)